# How can I solve my problem of receiving data via a socket?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am currently modernizing an HMI for this I use the platform UWP proposed by Microsoft. The old version of the HMI was developed in `C++` but for new needs, it is now developed in `C# / XAML`.

I take care of all the communication part of the application, it communicates permanently with a server.

To handle this connection, I use a socket and a background task to read the data permanently. At the connection level no problem, the application connects well to the server. By cons, I can not read the data received by the HMI.

Here is a part of the old code (part data recovery): (`C++`)

```
int ServerConnexion::server_input (ACE_HANDLE) {

  char data[2048]; 
  int tailleRecue = 0;

  switch (tailleRecue = peer().recv(data, sizeof(data))) {

    case -1:

          console.print("Read Error.");

    case 0:

          console.print("Closed");

    default:

            char *debutMsg = data; 
        int longueurMsg;

        do {
            longueurMsg = decodeMsg(debutMsg);
            debutMsg = debutMsg + longueurMsg; 
        } while (((debutMsg - data)  < tailleRecue) && (longueurMsg != -1));
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Now here is my code in the new HMI, this part is executed in the background task: (`C#`)

```
var socket = socketInformation.StreamSocket;
DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
await reader.LoadAsync(250);

var dataString = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
localSettingsData.Values["data"] = dataString;
```

Of course, I encounter a problem is this error is displayed:

```
No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page
```

How can I solve the problem?

Is there a function or method for reading and decoding bytes with UWP sockets?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbuffer) mentions both a `ReadBuffer` and a `ReadBytes` method.

Comment: From what I see in help DataReader is meant to be used to read data from database. You should use something else instead. [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient) maybe. And [BinaryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader).

Comment: @botje I tested but it does not work very well, do you have a sample code?

Comment: @Dialectius TcpClient replaces all the current login system that works it ...